# How to add a object To array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this object containing movies, and I'm trying to do add/modify a review based on the index.

```
let movies= {
      1: {"director": "Robert Wise","title": "The Sound of Music ", "reviews": [{"username" : "user1" , "review" : "good movie"} , {"username" : "user2" , "review" : "good watch"} ] },
      2: {"director": "Tony Richardson","title": "The Loved One ", "reviews": [] },
      3: {"director": "David Lean ","title": "Doctor Zhivago", "reviews": [] },
}
```

I'm trying to find the best way of doing that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: There is no JSON and no arrays in that code (except the reviews in the first item for some reason.)

Comment: In addition to ^^: Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals. Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add or modify a review based on the index, you can use the following code:

```
// Set the index of the movie you want to add/modify a review
let index = 1;

// Define the new review
let newReview = { "username": "user3", "review": "great movie!" };

// If the movie already has reviews, add the new review to the existing reviews array
if (movies[index]["reviews"]) {
  movies[index]["reviews"].push(newReview);
} 
// If the movie doesn't have any reviews, create a new array with the new review
else {
  movies[index]["reviews"] = [newReview];
}
```

This code first sets the index of the movie you want to add/modify a review for (in this case, it's movie with index 1). Then, it defines a new review object with a username and review.

The code then checks if the movie already has reviews by checking if the reviews property of the movie object is truthy (i.e., it's not null, undefined, empty, etc.). If it does, it adds the new review to the existing array using the push() method.

If the movie doesn't have any reviews yet, the code creates a new array with the new review object and assigns it to the reviews property of the movie object.

You can adjust the index variable and newReview object as needed to add or modify reviews for different movies.

Answer (score 1):

#### Make the "reviews" entry be an array, not an object (which is what you have for movies 2 and 3)

Then it is straightforward

```js
let movies= {
      1: {"director": "Robert Wise","title": "The Sound of Music ", "reviews": [{"username" : "user1" , "review" : "good movie"} , {"username" : "user2" , "review" : "good watch"} ] },
      2: {"director": "Tony Richardson","title": "The Loved One ", "reviews": [] },
      3: {"director": "David Lean ","title": "Doctor Zhivago", "reviews": [] },
}


movies[2].reviews.push({"username":"user2","review":"quite good"})


console.log(JSON.stringify(movies,null,2))
```

Comment: Thank you , the snippet that I've shared isn't mine , I was asked to add/update reviews and I was hesitant about changing the given code.

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer! 8-)